# How to set dialog title content programatically

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

is it possible to set up the HTML content of Kendo Dialog's titlebar programatically?
In HTML template, I can use the  tag, but is there any way to data-bind the complete html content or to set it programatically if I have a reference to a DialogComponent instance?

Thanks,
Tamas

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kendo-dialog-titlebar` to define any title you want with a custom template.

Try this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <kendo-dialog>
            <kendo-dialog-titlebar>
                <h3>{{title}}</h3>
            </kendo-dialog-titlebar>

            Sample text
        </kendo-dialog>
    `
})
class AppComponent {
    public title: string = "Title A";

    constructor() {
        setTimeout(() => this.title = "Title B", 2000);
    }
}
```

If you title is simple and you don't need anything but text you can simplify the above template like this:

```
template: `
    <kendo-dialog title={{title}}>
        Sample text
    </kendo-dialog>
`
```

Comment: Sure, this works. What I would like to achieve is to set up the title of the dialog through a custom directive. In the directive I provide a localization key like <kendo-dialog [locId]="'myDialog'" ...>, and the directive looks up the related title from a store, and sets it up for the dialog. But this title can be not only plain text but also html containing some tags. And I would like to avoid adding the <kendo-dialog-titlebar> tag to hundreds of dialogs, if this could be controlled from ts code somehow.